# netzke 0.8 not working with rails 4.0

Tags: extjs, ruby-on-rails-4, netzke

I am using netzke gem - ~> 0.8.0 version with rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0
I am getting an error when I start the rails server.
Basically, my routes code is like this:

```
RailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
    netzke
end
```

If I comment out netzke line, I dont have any problem with the routing. If not, rails throws an error saying use get or post and not match.
Is netzke compatible with rails 4.0?
How can I resolve it? Or should I use older version of rails for this to work.

Comment: You should use netzke 0.10.0.rc2
#Netzke
gem "netzke-core", "~> 0.10.0.rc2"
gem "netzke-basepack", "~> 0.10.0.rc2"

also add the 
#Protected Attributes
gem 'protected_attributes', '~> 1.0.7'

It will work with ext-4.2.1 and rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not support for Rails 4, You should use rails 3, and ruby 1.9